# Add dependent field to Mongoid's output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have two models:

```
class City
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :alternate_names, type: String
  field :coordinates, type: Array
  field :name, type: String

  index({ coordinates: '2d' }, { min: -180, max: 180 })

  belongs_to :country
end
```

and

```
class Country
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :iso_3166_code, type: String
  field :name, type: String

  has_many :cities
end
```

In the controller I use

`@cities = City.where(alternate_names: /#{params[:query].downcase}/).limit(10)`

to receive cities list.

Here is an JSON output for each city:

```
...

"country_id": {
  "$oid": "56fc453eae3bbe5c2abcd933"
}

...
```

How can I get `country` instead of it's `country_id`?

Comment: why can't you do `countries = @cities.map(&:country)` ?

Comment: It returns only countries, but I need full city object with countries embedded.

Comment: mongoid will do that for you so when you iterate through your `cities` each `city` will have  `country`...

Comment: `render json: @cities` returns `country_id` for each `city`, but I need `country`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
@cities = City.where(alternate_names: /#{params[:query].downcase}/).includes(:country).limit(10)

render json: @cities, except: :country_id, include: :country
```